# Oracle SQL Developer: Set the <null> value when exporting to CSV

Tags: oracle, export, oracle-sql-developer, csv

When exporting to CSV in Oracle SQL Developer, *null* values are replaced with "".  I want them to be exported as the string *null*.  Is this configurable anywhere?

Example of what is wished:

```
"STARTDATE", "ENDDATE"
"2017-03-16 00:00:00", null
```

instead of:

```
"STARTDATE", "ENDDATE"
"2017-03-16 00:00:00", ""
```

Exporting is performed by running a query, right-click on the data shown in the grid and select "Export..."

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just set the below in your session, as you would do in SQL*Plus:

```
set null "null"
```

Note: this will not affect how NULLs are displayed in the data grid (you can set that from the menu: *Tools - Preferences - Database - Advanced - Display Null Value As*), but it affects the exported CSV.

Comment: Learn something new every day :) +1

Comment: For some odd reason, I was running a 1.5.x version of Oracle SQL Developer for which 'set null "null"' returned an 'SQLPLUS Command Skipped:' error.  With the latest version (4.1.5), it works flawlessly.  Thank you.